# Que tengo que hacer para que la hora que mando desde java(NetBeans) a la base de datos coincidan?

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, date

La cuestión es que cuando mando un Timestamp desde java a la base de datos. la Base de datos phpMyAdmin lo recibe con 3 horas de mi hora local de mas y .Se puede arreglar esto?

```
public void agregarProyeccion(Proyeccion p){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO proyeccion( idSala, idPelicula, incioProy, finProy, estadoProy) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setInt(1,p.getIdSala().getIdSala());
            ps.setInt(2,p.getIdPelicula().getIdPelicula());
            ps.setTimestamp(3, p.getIncioProy());
            ps.setTimestamp(4, p.getFinProy());
            ps.setBoolean(5,p.isEstadoProy());
            
            ps.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            
            if (rs.next()) {
                p.setIdProyeecion(rs.getInt(1));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proyeccion Agregagada");
            }
            ps.close();
            
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Proyeccion no Agregagado " + ex );
        }
    }
```

de la vista lo mando asi

```
private void jAgregarButacaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
        Sala cli = (Sala) jComboSala.getSelectedItem();
        Pelicula pel = (Pelicula) jComboPelicula.getSelectedItem();

        LocalTime horaInicio = LocalTime.parse(horaIni.getText());
        LocalDate fechaNueva = jDateInico.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDateTime local = LocalDateTime.of(fechaNueva,horaInicio);
        Timestamp diaHoraincio = Timestamp.valueOf(local);
        
        LocalTime horafin = LocalTime.parse(horaFin.getText());
        LocalDate fechaNueva2 = jDateFin.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDateTime local2 = LocalDateTime.of(fechaNueva2, horafin);
        Timestamp diaHorafin = Timestamp.valueOf(local2);
        

        Proyeccion p = new Proyeccion(cli, pel, diaHoraincio,diaHorafin , true);

        pd.agregarProyeccion(p);

        limpiarCampos();
    }
```

la otra forma seria a la fecha sumarle las 3 horas pero no creo que sea muy funcional que digamos es proyecto de universidad y los profes no aportaron mucho que digamos pero bueno espero poder recibir ayuda saludos y gracias.

Comment: Lo primero: En tu pregunta no es evidente que los datos **estén guardados** con 3 horas más. Puede ser cosa de configuración de phpMyAdmin o del servidor que esté interpretando algo. Lo segundo: O sincronizas la hora en los servidores para que usen la misma zona horaria, o le añades la zona horaria al timestamp antes de enviarlo a la BD.

Comment: no se si es mas una configuración que código que puede ser pero no vi nada en la parte de phpMyAdmin que pueda cambiar o se refiera a fechas